# Is this enough to prove that every continuous function $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

In one exercise I am asked to prove that every continuous function $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}$- measurable.

I have an answer for this question but it does not look the same as the suggested one, so I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or the two are equivalent.

My answer goes as follows:

- We know that for every continuous function we have that the pre-image of an open set is again an open set.
- a function $u$ is $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}$- measurable  iff $u^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B},  \forall B\in\mathcal{O}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra, and $\mathcal{O}$ is the family of open sets on $\mathbb{R}$ ( a generator of the Borel sigma-algebra).

Hence I take an open set $B\in \mathcal{O}$ and by the first point we have that $u^{-1}(B)$ is an open set. It follows that $ u^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{B}$.

Is this enough as a prove?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is enough.

Comment: About the second point: Wouldn't it be more precise to first write "a function $u$ is $(\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B})$-measurable:  iff $u^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B},  \forall B\in\mathcal{B}$" (instead $\forall B\in\mathcal{O}$).

Comment: I wanted to make emphasis on the fact that I only need to check the condition on the generator of the sigma algebra. I agree with your first suggestion though.